# rsync without tarballs in MacPorts

Tags: macos, osx-lion, macports

After MacPorts was upgraded, I got some problems rsync'inking port tree. After this upgrade, MacPorts receives tarballs, and then uncompresses them. For my MacBook this is kind of trivial. Once in a while OS X is hanging.. for 3 minutes. I can't open new Finder windows, all processes are lagging like hell..

Is there's a way to bring back good old `rsync`? My connection is 100 Mbps – I don't need compression in here.

Comment: Macports always compresses these files. Try to monitor system log using "Console Utility" (in Utilities) to find out what's going wrong. Open this application and start the command which leads to problem (`macports selfupdate`?) and have a look at which lines get added. If you do not get along yourself with that, add these lines to your post (best would be editing not commenting). Do only remove lines you're very sure they've got nothing to do with this problem as this strange issue could be result of some side effects!

Comment: when launching macports with this command "sudo port -d selfupdate" I'm getting stacked at place where scripts extracts tarball file.. for a pretty long time you know.. so I would like to ged rid of these tarballs..

Comment: There must be some other problem. Try downloading some tarball and run `tar xvfz yourball.tar.gz`. Does this work? Then we know at least your tar and gz are fine.

Comment: well technically, for my old macbook, extracting so many small files takes 10x more then receive from internet one by one. my ping latency is quite good =) so.. tarballs extracts 10x longer then just rsync'ing

Comment: tarballs take some load from macports, you will not get around them. Try to fix your installation instead. Extracting these tarballs shouldn't take noticable longer than downloading these single files as more or less the same operations are performed. I expect that the additional effort on loading lots of small files is even bigger.

Comment: Jens: try for example, in freebsd, to get tarball with ports and extract it on slow machine.. and then try some csup method, if you have 100mbps you will see the difference..